# Elimination of unused virtual functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Is it possible to make MS linker drop `D::Unused` function from the simple code below?

```
class B {
  virtual const char* Unused() = 0;
};

class D : public B {
  const char* Unused() override;
};

const char* D::Unused() { return "this string is unused"; }

int main() {
  D* d = new D;
  delete d;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to achive this with vs2017 + `/OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /LTCG`, but resulting binary still contains bytes of `"this string is unused"` string.

Comment: Just guessing, but marking it `final` might do the trick...

Comment: I'm going to guess the answer is no.. but you can also try moving the class into an anonymous namespace if it's only ever used in one TU. That would let the compiler know that it's not needed. But I suspect it can't remove it because it would break bincompat of the v-table

Comment: @JesperJuhl, just tried to make both `D` and `D::Unused` - `final` without success.

Comment: @Mgetz, unfortunately in real program this class IS used from other units (but never the function itself)

Comment: @xpp_T then you're either left to eliminate that slot from the v-table (if you can and it won't break bin-compat) or you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

It probably cannot drop this function because this function is being referred to by the virtual table of `class D`. And the virtual table of `class D` is referred to by its constructor and destructor.

Comment: I'm sure this is the real reason. But why isn't it possible for linker optimizations to notice that this function body is redundant in the resulting executable? I'm not asking to remove vtable entry, just the referenced function body.

Comment: @xpp_T not and be compliant. The issue is that unless the compiler can prove the lifetime of the object it has to assume that virtual guarantees apply.